# Category image full width with title centred

Tags: magento2, category, category-image

I'm trying to redesign a category page to display the category image full width with a max height and have the category title displayed in the same box centred on the image.

I've managed to move the category image and title into the page wrapper with the below code

```
            <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
                <container name="amryw.container" as="amryw_container" label="Custom Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="amryw-container" after="main.content">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="comment.placeholder">
                    </block>
                </container>
            </referenceContainer>



<move element="amryw.container" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content" />
<move element="category.image" destination="amryw.container" before="main.content" />
<move element="page.main.title" destination="amryw.container" before="main.content" />
```

The HTML

```
<div class="amryw-container"><!-- Lorem Ipsum --><div class="page-title-wrapper">
    <h1 class="page-title"
         id="page-title-heading"                     aria-labelledby="page-title-heading&#x20;toolbar-amount"
        >
        <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper" >Classic Wax Melts</span>    </h1>
    </div>
<div class="category-image"><img src="https://and-it.co.uk/test-store/pub/media/catalog/category/amryw-classic-wax-melts-banner.jpg" alt="Classic&#x20;Wax&#x20;Melts" title="Classic&#x20;Wax&#x20;Melts" class="image" /></div></div>
```

The CSS

```
.amryw-container {
    display: contents;
}
.category-image {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    align-self: center;
    display: contents;
}
.category-image .image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 340px;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

But can't figure out how to get the title to be in the centre of the image.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Page I'm trying to edit: https://and-it.co.uk/test-store/classic-wax-melts

Page I'm trying to replicate: https://amryw.co.uk/classic-wax-melts/

**UPDATE**

This is now what my catalog_category_view.xml looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>


<referenceContainer name="category.view.container">

<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="custom.category.top.view" template="Magento_Catalog::category/view/custom_category_title.phtml" before="main.content" />

</referenceContainer>
<move element="category.view.container" destination="page.wrapper" before="main.content" />
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>


        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Codazon\ThemeLayoutPro\Block\Catalog\Subcategories" name="cdz-subcategories" template="Magento_Catalog::category/subcategories.phtml" before="category.products.list.container" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And this is custom_category_title.phtml located at

```
<?php

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
    $_currentCat = $block->getCurrentCategory();
    $categoryTitle = $_currentCat->getTitle();
    $categoryImage = $_currentCat->getImageUrl();

?>

<div>
   <div class="category-image">
       <img title="<?=$categoryTitle?>" alt="<?=$categoryTitle?>" src="<?=$categoryImage?>">
       <h1><?=$categoryTitle?></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to build your custom block and remove the 2 basic one's (or rewrite them)
my suggestion for what you would like to accomplish is to Remove the

```
category.image
page.main.title
```

and add a custom one,
just to have a cleaner css and html code.

You should be able to accomplish that like this:

CSS:

```
.category-image-custom img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: top;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
}

.category-image-custom h1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    right: 40%;
    font-size: 30px;
    font: 400 50px/1.2 Poiret One, Helvetica Neue, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}

.category-image-custom {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    align-self: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="category-image-custom">
      <img title="" alt="" src="https://and-it.co.uk/test-store/pub/media/catalog/category/amryw-classic-wax-melts-banner.jpg">
      <h1>Classic Wax Melts</h1>
</div>
```

To do as i suggested you'll need to do as such in category_view.xml in your custom template:

catalog_category_view.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="category.view.container">

    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="custom.category.top.view" template="category/view/custom_category_title.phtml"/>

</referenceContainer>
<referenceBlock name="category.image" remove="true"/>
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
```

create your PHTML inside your theme \ module :
(Note, if you have a custom theme inherited from Luma you can just place it inside: Magento_Catalog\templates\category\view\custom_category_title.phtml,

instead if you have only a custom module you'll have to place the Layout.xml [catalog_category_view] and the template [custom_category_title] inside your module: Vendor_Module\view\frontend\layout\catalog_category_view.xml and Vendor_Module\view\frontend\templates\category\view\custom_category_title.phtml)

\category\view\custom_category_title.phtml

```
<?php

/**
 * Category view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View
 */
    $_currentCat = $block->getCurrentCategory();
    $categoryTitle = $_currentCat->getName();
    $categoryImage = $_currentCat->getImageUrl();

?>

<div>
   <div class="category-image-custom">
       <img title="<?=$categoryTitle?>" alt="<?=$categoryTitle?>" src="<?=$categoryImage?>">
       <h1><?=$categoryTitle?></h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'm not entirely sure I know how to do that though. I've managed to create a container and move elements into it, but suspect this isn't what you mean. I've updated the OP with where I'm at now if you can offer any guidance.

Comment: i've edited my answer, removing the base one's and substitute them with the custom one should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for the extra info! I understand what's supposed to happen now but at a loss as to where these files should actually go. I'm using a custom theme but unsure if it's derived from luma. I can't see any module folder or view folder in the app directory od my theme.

Comment: Then you have to create it, in your theme folter (App/Design/Frontend/"Vendor"/"Theme"/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml) and (App/Design/Frontend/"Vendor"/"Theme"/Magento_Catalog/template/category/view/custom_category_title.phtml), to check if the Theme is inherited go check admin side: Content -> Design -> Theme -> "Custom theme" check the "Parent voice"

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I'm having some success. I've updated my original question with how things are looking now.

So what is happening now is it's trying to get the category image from the correct url, but is showing broken link on the loaded page. Following the URL directly loads the image. The H1 tags are also empty and the category title isn't displaying. Finally the category description has jumped above the category image.

Comment: Try using <?php Echo $categoryTitle ?> sometime the Short code for echo :<?= ?> have to be enabled and depends on the php configuration

Comment: That still doesn't do it unfortunately. It's trying to pull the image from from and-it.co.uk/pub/media...etc so I don't think that will be a problem once it moves to its correct domain. But the H1 tags are still empty.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited the answer, the problem was that there's no category "Title" but category "Name" instead $_currentCat->getName();

Comment: That did the trick for the title. Thank you. Styling is a bit off, could that be down to the image not loading?

And why would the category description decide to move? Wondering if I can move this back with the 'move element'

Comment: The styling is a bit off because category-image got some basic css of it's own conflicting with our new one, i've edited the answer so now the class "category-image" is now "category-image-custom". And Yes you can move the category description: <move element="category.description" destination="category.view.container" after="-"/>

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much. I've been racking my brains for days on this and never would have got it.

Final question, will the image not loading correct itself when I move the magento install to the correct domain removing the need for the /test-store/ in the url?

Comment: the problem is that you've got a wordpress website and a magento 2 site (the test one) if you set up correctly when "migrating" i guess, you should be good. As you can see Magento 2 is searching the image in: "/pub/media/catalog/category/amryw-classic-wax-melts-banner.jpg" and the production site have a wp-content/uploads

Comment: That's great. Thank you for all the help. Really appreciated.